# Creature crawling under surface of walls - Horror movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I recall a horror movie featuring a human-like creature/monster that moved under the surface of the building, walls, carpets, and even the kitchen sink, causing the plates to fall to the ground.
Actually I did not see the whole movie, so I'm not sure about its details, instead I saw a "special-effects" show several years ago that investigated the 3D effects used in the film.

Can you help find it? I've not seen such creatures in any other movies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not really a lot to go on, but it sounds like the opening to [The Frighteners](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116365/) - a movie by Peter Jackson.

You can watch the opening sequence at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApZ5wmaQcVE - the special effects become apparent at about 1:20

It's a pretty good film - with some excellent turns by Jeffrey Combs and Michael J Fox, and has some really funny moments thanks to Jackson's writing/directing.

Thinking about it, and I do remember that there was a "special-effects" behind the scenes doco made for this movie - which was what made me want to watch it in the first place

Comment: Man, you definitely found it in the first try! Thanks. I saw several scenes I remembered from the past in the link you posted. 

As a side question do you know any other story with such creatures? I feel this was a unique feature of this movie.

Answer (score 1):

It could be [Nightmare on Elm Street 3: Dream Warriors](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093629/). There's a dream sequence where the walls and floors ripple and burst *as if* some horrible Bugs Bunny were burrowing underneath.