# Name of this early 2000s alien horror movie where children are probed by aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror

I'm looking for the name of an alien horror movie where children are probed by aliens. and then the aliens come back for them as adults. I think the probes are used to locate the children when they become adults.

I think the movie is from the early 2000s, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 10):

That sounds a little like "They", a 2002 horror movie. Strange monsters from an alternate dimension kidnap children and put needle like implants in them, then return the children a few days later. When the children are adults, the monsters come back for them and take them forever. Their motives are never explained. The monsters are repelled by light, if that reminds you of anything. [There is a pretty good synopsis on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_(2002_film)).

Comment: Why do you add some junk at the back of your link?

Comment: @user21820 The "?wprov=sfla1" part is for Wikipedia's analytics. When you click on it that part tells Wikipedia you got there via a shared link rather than a natural search.

Comment: @Logarr: So it **is indeed** junk, thanks for that information.

Comment: Related question and answer here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122273/what-horror-movie-features-half-human-crawling-creatures-with-no-eyes/